# Invert position of time and date

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, datetime

If I have a datetime standard (dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss) is there a possible to invert position of time and date and get hh:mm:ss dd/MM/yyyy ?

I tried

```
var tempDate = date.ToString("hh:mm:ss dd/MM/yyyy");

date = Convert.ToDateTime(tempDate);
```

But I keep get the date in first format (dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss).

**New Info**

As per conversation with the OP, the motivation here is that the date needs to be displayed in the grid in the specific format. The model that contains `DateTime` Property is part of the list. **Question is**, "How to make date appear in the specific format in the grid?"

Comment: What do you mean you keep getting it in the first format? Where? Are you displaying `date` somewhere? I don't understand why you're doing `.ToString()` on a date just to parse it right back into a `DateTime` again.

Comment: "But I keep get the date in first format (dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss)." No, you get a `DateTime` value. A `DateTime` itself doesn't have any format - just like an `int` has no concept of whether it was parsed from hex or decimal. If you want a particular string representation, format it that way when you need to. (I suspect you want `HH` rather than `hh` though, as at the moment there'll be no difference between 8am and 8pm...)

Comment: Why are you converting your string back to a date? `tempDate` should contain your desired result - a `DateTime`-object does not include its output format.

Comment: `DateTime` value has no format. You specify the format when you convert `DateTime` to a `string`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets walk this one. Here you have a date you presenting as a string in a specific format

```
var tempDate = date.ToString("hh:mm:ss dd/MM/yyyy");
```

This, I am not sure why it is working for you at all without supplying Format Provider

```
date = Convert.ToDateTime(tempDate);
```

This program did not work for me (as expected!) because the culture of my thread (format provider) does not have parsing mechanism to such string as I receive from the line 1

```
var tempDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss dd/MM/yyyy");
Console.WriteLine(tempDate); // Prints the date
var date = Convert.ToDateTime(tempDate);  //ERROR !!!
Console.WriteLine(date);
```

`DateTime` is not stored in any specific format. It is a special data type. What you see on the screen is a string representation of this type. Here `Console.WriteLine(date);`, as example, `date` being converted to a string using its internal logic in default `ToString()` implementation, using current thread's culture. Or you can use `ToString(...)` parameterized overloads to get out a specific format, e.g. `"hh:mm:ss dd/MM/yyyy"`. But storing this format in `DateTime` is not possible. Format comes from the culture, which your thread currently is set with, unless you specify it. You can try to change culture on the thread and you will see different results from `ToString()` for each culture.

**To Answer the question as it came up from conversation with OP**, you can do the following

```cs
// imagine this is as original model
public class DataModel
{ 
    // Other propertues here 
    public DateTime DateProperty { get; set; }
}

// create display model
public class DisplayModel
{
    privvate const string _format = "hh:mm:ss dd/MM/yyyy";
    private DataModel _dataModel;

    public DisplayModel(DataModel dataModel)
    {
        _dataModel = dataModel;
    }

    // Wraps date time and 
    public string DateProperty { get { return _dataModel.ToString(_format); } }

    // other properties here

}
```

This is possible general approach for whatever UI needs. However, if the grid you've mentioned is `DataGridView`, even simpler approach would be is to set a property on the grid

```
dataGrid.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "hh:mm:ss dd/MM/yyyy";
```

Comment: So, for example, if I have a class with a DateTime, I can't print this class directly because the format will be always dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss right? Just to be more clear, I'm using a kendo grid to show values, but I want to change the format of the datetime as I explained.

Comment: @RobNone Do you mean, a class with a `DateTime` property? And when you say `print class`, what do you mean? Do you mean `public override string ToString()` in your class, where you can do `return MyProperty.ToString()`?? If you `ToString()` your date , you will get default format of the current thread. If you use `ToString(string)` you will get specified format. You can use "standard formats" like `ToString("g")`. These are also culture specific

Comment: I have this DateTime as a property of my class, and I have a list of this object. When the list go to the grid, I need to show the datetime in the other format.

Comment: @RobNone In this case you need to use a wrapper to this class, AKA Proxy or Decorator, where you create same property and do `get { return _innerClass.DateProperty.ToString(myFormat); }`...

Comment: @RobNone I updated the question/answer based on the new info you gave to me